# Where do you put your gesture commands in Xamarin? In the View Model?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I currently have a view model looking like this:

```
public class PhrasesFrameViewModel : ObservableProperty
{
    bool customPointsSwitch;

    public PhrasesFrameViewModel()
    {

        var aButtonClickedCommand = new Command(() =>
        {
            App.DB.IncrementScore(App.cfs, App.phrase, (int)App.aBtn);
            App.correctButtonPressed = (int)App.aBtn;
            ResetTimer2();
        });

        var wordGridClickedCommand = new Command(() =>
        {
            if (App.Timer1Running)
                ResetTimer1();
            else
                ResetTimer2();
        });

    }

    private static void ResetTimer1()
    {
        if (App.tokenSource1 != null)
        {
            App.Timer1Seconds = 0;
            App.tokenSource1.Cancel();
        }
    }

    private static void ResetTimer2()
    {
        if (App.tokenSource2 != null)
        {
            App.Timer2Seconds = 0;
            App.tokenSource2.Cancel();
        }
    }

    public bool CustomPointsSwitch
    {
        get
        {
            return customPointsSwitch;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value != customPointsSwitch)
            {
                customPointsSwitch = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("CustomPointsSwitch");
                App.DB.UpdateBoolSetting(Settings.Cp, customPointsSwitch);
            }
        }
    }
```

I believe most view models would have code similar to that for CustomPointsSwitch but how about the code for the gesture recognizers and the commands plus the small method for reset (used by a few other methods in the view model).  Does that all belong in the view model or should it be in another class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short answer:** In this particular case, as per code shared in question, they belong in view model.

**Long answer:** 
It depends. If your command handler needs to interact with UI - it should stay in view; If it is anything else, i.e. presentation or business logic - it should be defined in view model.

Commands are integral part of MVVM pattern - as they allow for decoupling of view model from view, which in turn makes it easier to unit test, maintain and extend. They are the recommended channel for communication between view and view-model (other than data-binding).

In most of the cases, the command interface is used when a user-interaction/event in view needs to trigger various actions in the  view-model - and in these cases command is defined in view-model itself and exposed as a property.